# How to change display text in Django Tables 2 Link Column

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tables2

I am using django tables 2 to list items and I am trying to add a column with a hyperlink to another page (an edit details page) with the selected row details using its primary key in the model.
I have used a link column as here which works(the link opens the expected page) but it is showing the **itemid** in the column while I want to put a link who's display text is marked "Edit". Can any help with how I can do that? I want to mimic the `<a href="myurl"> Edit </a>` behaviour

```
# tables.py
class MyItemsTable(tables.Table):
    itemid = tables.LinkColumn('myapp.views.edit_item', 
                        args=[A('pk')],orderable=False)
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyItems
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}

# views.py      
def myitems_list(request):
    myitems = models.MyItems.objects.all()
    table = tables.MyItemsTable(myitems)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'myapp/mylist.html', {'table':table,'myitems':myitems})

def edit_item(request, pk):
    selecteditem = get_object_or_404(models.MyItems, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'myapp/edit_item.html', {'selecteditem': selecteditem})

# models.py
class MyItems(models.Model):
    itemid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    itemfullname = models.TextField('Full Name',blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Overide data content of a django-tables2 LinkColumn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198701/django-overide-data-content-of-a-django-tables2-linkcolumn)

Comment: Actually turns out the solution was using a Template Column as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211301/django-tables2-linkcolumn-external-url

Comment: The Template Column of course is the *obvious* solution. What I propose to my answer in the duplicate question is the *DRY* solution !

Comment: :-) Django Noobie mistake, I didn't understand your suggested answer and I found a simple solution that worked. Went with 'Simple is better than complex' rather guessing. Many thanks for the approach. I shall dissect it until I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably solved this but there is a better way of adding custom text instead of using a `TemplateColumn`, and the functionality is actually already built in to a `LinkColumn`. To add your edit string:

```
# tables.py
class MyItemsTable(tables.Table):
    itemid = tables.LinkColumn('myapp.views.edit_item', 
                    args=[A('pk')], orderable=False, text='Edit')
class Meta:
    model = models.MyItems
    attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

You can make the string dynamic to whatever you want using something like `text=lambda record: 'edit-{0}'.format(record.name)` for example. Have a look at the [documentation](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#linkcolumn) .